# Xpath not working in camel route

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I'm sending soap xml through exchange object.When i try to route the request using xpath in apache camel,i'm not able to execute it properly.Please suggest
My Exchange body xml is

```
 <Envelope><Header>
  </Header>
    <Body>
     <Choice>
        <Selector>1</selector>
    </Choice>
   </Body>
 </Envelope>
```

My Camel Route

```
from(direct:XX)
  .to(when(xpath("body()/Choice/Selector/.",String.class)=='1')
  .to("direct:X")
  .otherwise()
  .to("direct:Y")
```

Comment: Study how xpath works, and mind about namespaces

Answer (score 1):

1. your Envelope cannot look like that. it must be something like:

   ```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Header/>    
      <soapenv:Body>
       ...
   ```
2. `body()/Choice/Selector/.` is not an Xpath. there is no such thing like `body()` in XPath.

Assuming that you have a SOAP Body content in the Exchange.body processed by some JAX-WS endpoint XPath will be

`/Choice/Selector` or `/Choice/Selector/text()` if it is an element with mixed content

BTW: if your `Envelope` is real example you try to test do not forget to fix your XML - you have wrong `<Selector>1</selector>` Tag names are case sensitive. It must be `<Selector>1</Selector>`

Comment: And you must use namespace mapping also for xpaths to work. Read the docs: http://camel.apache.org/xpath